# Generating Dataflow Template Using Python

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have python script that creates dataflow template in the specified GCS path. I have tested the script using my GCP Free Trial and it works perfect.
My question is using same code in production environment I want to generate a template but I can not use Cloud-Shell as there are restrictions also can not directly run the Python script that is using the SA keys.
Also I can not create VM and using that generate a template in GCS.
Considering above restrictions is there any option to generate the dataflow template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Composer, I have triggered the Dataflow DAGs which created Jobs in dataflow. Also managed to generate Dataflow template. Using Dataflow console & template executed the job

Answer (score 0):

Using dataflow [flex templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates) should obviate the need to automatically generate templates--instead you could create a single template that can be parameterized arbitrarily.